# In Manim, how do you move the left edge of an object to a particular vector?

Tags: python, manim

When I specify where to move it to, it moves the center of the object there. But my text objects are all different lengths and I want their left edges to line up.

```
class TextAlign(Scene):
def construct(self):
    my_text1 = TextMobject("Text")
    my_text2 = TextMobject("Longer Text")

    vector1 = np.array([-3, 2, 0])
    vector2 = np.array([-3, 1, 0])

    my_text1.move_to(vector1)
    my_text2.move_to(vector2)

    self.add(my_text1)
    self.add(my_text2)
```

[image]

Comment: Try `my_text2.align_to(my_text1, LEFT)`